# All instances have theselves method?

Tags: function, oop, object, methods, programming-languages

out of curiosity, Methods are also have multiple area on memory with same codes?

i make sense that functions are only one and have one area on memory.

but, there are concepts class and instance in the Object Oriented Programming

and instances' function are method as i know.

Functions are only one, but Methods are not(many instances.. then would be many methods..)

i think they are only one code area on memory for methods and multiple area on memory for properties. but they use something special like stack-frame then can do something like referring instance objects etc....

it's correct on something like C++, java, python, javascript?

Answer (score 0):

There is a single implementation of each method; a single copy.

At runtime, a reference to the object instance is passed to the method, either implicitly (in languages like Java), or explicitly (like the `self` argument in Python).

In dynamic languages, the methods available for an object are attributes of the class, or the object, so it's possible to have different objects of the same class have different implementations of the same method name.

Comment: Thank you. you mean it can be available on dynamic programming languages then the language do or don't?